# Setting up setattr behavior of Django model without affecting instance initialization

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called A. When b attribute is set of that model, I want to update that attribute like this:

```
# Note that PGJSONField is a field that can store string or json.

class A(models.Model):
    description = PGJSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        if key == 'description':
            val = {'description': val}
        super(A, self).__setattr__(key, val)
```

This causes a side effect. When I get model instance from DB. It set's up description key as dict event if it's not.

```
>>> a = A.objects.first()
>>> a.description
..: {"description": "lorem ipsum"}
```

My expected bahavior is something like this:

```
>>> a = A.objects.first()
>>> a.description
..: "lorem ipsum"
>>> a.description = "foo bar"
>>> a.description = {"description": "foo bar"}
```

I think I must by pass **_setattr** method when model is being fetched but I couldn't find a way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want string description with lots of key-val pair than use a different model altogether which will make storing easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this model structure it will make your storing efficient 
if data security is not needed

```
class A(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class KeyVal(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(A)
    key       = models.CharField(max_length=240, db_index=True)
    value     = models.CharField(max_length=240, db_index=True)
```

So if you know the name in A-table you can get all key-value pairs, key-list, value-list